# SED Usage properly to change line

Tags: sed

I would like to change the line with the below replacement

```
STUNNIX_BIN_PATH=~/bpd/external/stunnix-cxx-obfus/bin
STUNNIX_BIN_PATH=/home/test-matcher/Obfuscated_Tools/stunnix-cxx-obfus
```

I tried a little bit using `sed` command but unable to replace `/home/` string in the `~ string` using the below commands. Can anyone help ?

```
sed -i 's/~/home/g' /home/test-matcher/Sources/QMMatcher/$(date +"%m_%d_%y")_"$2_Viper"/scripts/obfuscate/qmobfus.sh
sed -i 's/bpd/test-matcher/g' /home/test-matcher/Sources/QMMatcher/$(date +"%m_%d_%y")_"$2_Viper"/scripts/obfuscate/qmobfus.sh
sed -i 's/external/Obfuscated_Tools/g' /home/test-matcher/Sources/QMMatcher/$(date +"%m_%d_%y")_"$2_Viper"/scripts/obfuscate/qmobfus.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use any char as separator in sed

try

```
sed -i 's:~/bpd/external/stunnix-cxx-obfus/bin:/home/test-matcher/Obfuscated_Tools/stunnix-cxx-obfus:' ...
```

I am not sure you need `/g` flag. this is only usefull if you want multiple replace on same line.